# Why did a moderator delete my account?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts, specific-site

I don't know how to be clearer that a moderator deleted my old account.

1. Yesterday when I logged on Money, I saw "Join this community", but I never deleted my Money account. I then clicked "Join this community".
2. Screen shot beneath undeniably proves this wasn't my old account. I asked at least 5 questions. It's unquestionably false that "you have not asked any questions."
3. Please reinstate my old account?

I can't post on Money Meta. Please don't betray private details.

[image]

Comment: I've changed your discussion tag to one for support because I cannot see that the evidence you present for your account having been deleted is undeniable.   I think you should find out if it actually happened before asking why.

Comment: You were told in the previous thread that your account was suspended.

Comment: @connectyourcharger yes, but they didn't answer 2 and 3. how else do you explain them?

Comment: @MarkdaSilva 2. I guess you accidentally made a new account. 3. No. You were suspended (not deleted) for voting fraud.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate?

Answer (score 10):

I just visited [your account on Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/91921/mark-da-silva), and it says:

> This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends on Nov 26 '20 at 13:36.

This account has been suspended.  It has not been deleted.

Only a moderator on that site or an SE staff member will be able to investigate the existence and possible deletion of any other accounts of yours on that site.  My recommendation, to avoid confusion between multiple accounts on a site, is to only ever have one.

Comment: But my previous account appears to have been deleted. Did you read my edited post?

Comment: Yes - see my edit to this post..

Comment: Your recommendation to "only ever have one [account]" isn't very helpful. The OP only _wants_ one account...

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica when I see "voting irregularities" my first thought is sock puppets.  My reading of the question is that its asker wants a particular account back.  Waiting for a Personal Finance & Money mod or an SE staff member to see the question here is really the only way forward if the [Contact Us button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) or responding to a mod message is not used.

Comment: Agreed, this whole thing should be an interaction with support/staff/mods

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica But suspension bars me from posting on money SE?

Comment: Who suggested doing that, @Mark?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: @polygeo "It has not been deleted." how do you explain 2 and 3 then?

Comment: @MarkdaSilva To explain 2, you haven't asked any questions *on the account you just created*. Obviously if you create a new profile, it's not going to have the questions from your old one. I can't explain 3 as I'm not privy to why you were banned, but you would have to make a better case then "I wasn't told about the ban, please unban me".

Comment: @F1Krazy I don't think you understood 2. "when I asked at least 5 questions"

Comment: @MarkdaSilva You asked at least five questions *on your previous account*. You are looking at a *completely different account*. No offence, but how is this so hard for you to grasp?

Comment: @F1Krazy What happened to my previous account then? I didn't delete it.

Comment: @MarkdaSilva As PolyGeo stated, it has been banned for a year due to "voting irregularities". That's why you can't log into it. I can grab a screenshot for you if you don't believe me.

Comment: @F1Krazy Can you see my old account's questions?

Comment: @MarkdaSilva Now that you mention it, I can't. Either they were deleted, or you're referring to a different account that really was deleted. Would you happen to remember the names of some of the questions? Perhaps they're still there, but disassociated from your account.

Comment: You keep talking about your old account, and show us no evidence that it ever existed.  If it did exist and has been deleted, then only  a Personal Finance & Money mod or an SE staff member will be able to investigate it.  All we can see is that the account you are using here has been suspended from Personal Finance & Money.

Comment: You have now provided evidence that a moderator removed your other account but I think it unreasonable for you to claim I ignored that evidence before you provided it.